Why don't Western countries confiscate frozen Russian assets?
As reported by euromaiden, it seems this G7 summit will produce an agreement to use the investment profits of the frozen Russian assets, commonly said to be around us$330 billion, for the purpose of defending and reconstructing Ukraine. The particular mechanism currently reported is to use the annual proceeds as repayments to a new ~us$50 billion loan to Ukraine.
A related question is thus why not use the frozen assets more directly? Can they, for example, not be used to collateralize loans to Ukraine for defense and reconstruction?
In that note, European countries are often reported as being reticent of directly using frozen Russian assets, and the current report of using the proceeds is a way of compromise.
Why do these European capitals reject using frozen Russian assets directly -- assuming they do? Why does Biden administration push for it -- surely they face the same pros and cons in front of them? What are the pros and cons of confiscating Russian state assets frozen in Western countries?

I can start by linking some contextual observations:

As Creon Butler from Chatham House argues, if the confiscation of frozen Russian assets results in even 5bp rise in borrowing costs of Western countries permanently, the net present value would already exceed the frozen assets in question.

Frozen Russian assets nonminimally kept intact incentivizes peace negotiation and settlement.

It is illegal currently and against international norms to seize sovereign foreign assets. As US Senator Rand Paul argues, that is the purview of a directly injured state, not a third-party country with which Russia is not at war.


These are some factors outside observers can make. What are the reasons of the actual capitals pushing one way or the other? Maybe there are non-English sources revelling their reasonings?
